# Codeigniter -> Content not displaying

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have created a foreach loop in my view to get the content that I have requested from the database fullpath = full image and description = alt tag but it does not seem to be passing the data through into the content view:

**View**

```
<?php if(is_array($get_images)): ?>

            <?php foreach($get_images as $image): ?>
            <img src ="<?=base_url()?>includes/uploads/gallery/<?=$image->fullpath?>" alt="<?= $image->description?>">
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**Controller**

```
   $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
   $data['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();
   $data['title'] = 'Delete Gallery Image'; 
   $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/deleteimage',NULL,TRUE); 

  $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data);
```

**Model**

```
    function getImages() {
        $query = $this->db->get('images');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: how about doing `print_r($get_images);` in your view, i bet it's null!

Comment: Done that it shows nothing so is NULL -> I just dont get why!

Comment: the issues is here `$query = $this->db->get('images');` for some reason it's not returning any rows, as your doing a count that evaluates to false, the `return $query->result();` does not get executed meaning nothing is returned by the function, you need to check your connected to the correct database, there is a table called images, and there are rows within that table.

Comment: `$data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/deleteimage',NULL,TRUE);` is being passed NULL, thus the only variables it knows are NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'Images' data should be in a differnt array.

try;

```
// load images in to our $page array();
$page['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();

// load our main template data in to the $data array();
$data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
$data['title'] = 'Delete Gallery Image'; 
// load our $page array() in to our content subview.
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/deleteimage', $page, TRUE); 

// output all the conbine $page array() and $data array() in to the main view
$this->load->view('admintemplate', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue should be down to one of the following:

- Your not corrected to the correct database
- Your database does not contain a table called **images**
- your table called *images* is empty.

After doing your database check's make sure your error reporting is switched on, either to output or to log files.

Check the log's to see if there is anything related to your issue.

---

Updated:

Change your function to the following:

```
function getImages()
{
    $rows = array();
    foreach($this->db->get('images')->result() as $row)
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Comment: Robert, There is data and the db is connected fine, http://cl.ly/3E3n0N1d1C241e3Z0F0Z

Comment: Ive updated my answer with a possible solution, it seems you was returing a single object, thus why it was failing, looping the results into a result an array and then return should work better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel like you provided enough context, but the only thing I can guess is...

```
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/deleteimage',NULL,TRUE);
```

You're passing `NULL` into it as opposed to passing `$data`.  Otherwise as everyone else is saying, you should probably prove that $data['get_images'] actually has data ;).  Also... any reason the variable isn't just named $images?, just curious ^^.

Instead of `$data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/deleteimage',NULL,TRUE);`

You want some:

`$data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/deleteimage',$data,TRUE);`